# Set translation locale on form_widget in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have symfony form with choice type.
In choices I have something like this:

```
'entity.rental_conditions.prepayment_options.no_prepayment' => 0,
'entity.rental_conditions.prepayment_options.prepayment_amount' => 1,
'entity.rental_conditions.prepayment_options.prepayment_percent' => 2,
'entity.rental_conditions.prepayment_options.full_amount' => 3
```

and I show this choice type in Twig - `{{ form_widget(form.prepayment.type) }}`

My application is multilanguage with default locale DE (German lang) and my question is how can I set another locale for form_widget, for example, English to show choices options not in all languages in my app, only in EN?

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, how do you introduce international languages to an app? There is a [LanguageType field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/language.html) which you can use to set a user's language in their profile or upon sign-up.

There's also a [Translations Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html) which is a multi-step process to allow translations to multiple languages.